# Disable route unless (condition) - React, Routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**The Issue:**

I am facing an issue routing to a nested route (`ExamResult` component), I'd like to disable any kind of navigation to this specific route unless I've submitted a form.

**Demo video:**

https://www.screencast.com/t/cayuOnsa8

**Code:**

*App.js* `Routes` :

```js
<Routes>

    ...

    <Route path='exams/:id' element={<ExamPage />} >
        <Route path='result' element={<ExamResult />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='exams/:id/add-question' element={<RequireAuth><AddQuestion /></RequireAuth>}/>

    {/* <Route path='exams/:id/result' element={<ExamResult />} /> */}

    ...

    <Route path='*' element={<NoMatch />} />
</Routes>
```

*QuestionList.js* `Component` - Navigation to `result` route after quiz submission:

```
navigate('result', { state });
```

**Repo:** [*quiz-react-storybook*](https://github.com/BloodShop/quiz-react-storybook)
**Github Open Issue:** [*issue*](https://github.com/BloodShop/quiz-react-storybook/issues/1)

**Expectations:**

Only after I'm submitting the quiz I would expect the navigation to work, otherwise navigating to `exams/:id/result` path won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `ExamPage` component must render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to rendered. You could conditionally render the `Outlet` based on whether or not the form has been submitted.

```
...

{formSubmitted && <Outlet />}

...
```

An alternative method might be to pass some route state along with the route transition to the `"exams/:id/result"` route and check in `ExamResult` whether or not the navigation was valid and issue a back navigation if it wasn't.

```
navigate(
  'result',
  {
    state: {
      ...state,
      formSubmitted: true,
    }
  }
);
```

ExamResult

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { state } = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  if (!state?.formSubmitted) {
    navigate(-1);
  }
}, []);

...
```

Comment: I managed to implement this answer, really good explanation. Also this route `https://.../exams/4/result` is still presented at the url.

Comment: @AlonKolyakov Well, the first method just prevents the route from being accessible, if you need to fix/synchronize the UI/address bar then you'll need to handle that in `ExamPage` similar to the second example.

Comment: Well I am facing this url issue, for example: I've submitted the quiz and got the results (url=`https://.../exams/4/result`); if I refresh the page the url stays and kinda breaks the state.. Here is a short demonstration: https://www.screencast.com/t/zgtBrLm61p

Comment: @AlonKolyakov You may need to persist some component state (*selected quiz answers, form submitted, etc*) to localStorage and re-initialize state from localStorage if you need to retain the state *through* a page reload. Page reloads remount the entire app, so any React state will be lost/reset.

Answer (score 0):

manage global state(ex. - Submitted: false) in context or redux to check whether the form is submitted or not. set this state to true on submit.

in result component based on condition return result's JSX or navigate to home if Submitted = false.